# jQuery slide to limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got a div-block in a table that slides Up/Down. Now this block has by default the style "display: none;" and if it slides down it extends the table column if the width of the block is higher than the one of the column. I do not want that to happen, so i want to slideUp up to 1px at max so it stays extended.

Are there any simple solutions for that?

Comment: Example codes will help understand your question better

Answer (score 2):

Can you maybe add a position absolute to your block and the parent container should has a overflow:hidden property.

It's maybe not what you are looking for, but i think it can be a solution.

Comment: This would not work for me. Then my table does not get extended at all and the block could be at the bottom corner of the site, so in those cases i would not see the content of the block.

Comment: If you get the height of your cell in jquery, you can't limit the slidedown? by limiting in css the height of the sliding element?

Comment: jquery seems to ignore the min-height property of an element when using slideUp. I could try using animate, but i do not think it will help.

Comment: And if you set the height of the element at the end of the slide?